Button is not dynamic enough to adapt to different screen sizes
When I try to wrap everything with Container without SingleChildScrollView, I found that my content is being pushed by the Container, I've tried some solution like resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false and resizeToAvoidBottomPadding and somehow it didn't work. So I try another solution which wrap everything with SingleChildScrollView and then make the physics NeverScrollPhysics but the button can't be seen since it's too low, so how do I fix it?
enter image description here
Here's my code below
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class TwoStepVerification extends StatefulWidget {
  const TwoStepVerification({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TwoStepVerificationState createState() => _TwoStepVerificationState();
}

class _TwoStepVerificationState extends State<TwoStepVerification> {
  bool _isPhone = true;

  FocusNode phoneText = FocusNode();

  TextEditingController phoneInput = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Container(
          width: 200,
          child: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(10.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                    value: 1, // Value for first step
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xD9D9D9D9),
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 7.0),
                Expanded(
                  child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                    value: 0.5, // Value for second step
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xD9D9D9D9),
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 7.0),
                Expanded(
                  child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                    value: 0.0, // Value for third step
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xD9D9D9D9),
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-30,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                        'Set up 2-step verification',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 24.0,
                          fontFamily: "GraphikMedium"
                        )
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                    Text(
                      'Enter your phone number so we can text you an authentication code.',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        color: Colors.grey[700]
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Phone',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            color: phoneText.hasFocus ? Colors.blue : Colors.black,
                            fontFamily: "GraphikMedium"
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                        Focus(
                          onFocusChange: (focus){
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          child: TextFormField(
                            controller: phoneInput,
                            focusNode: phoneText,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                              FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                            ],
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)
                              ),
                              errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
                              ),
                              focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
                              ),
                              hintText: 'Your phone number',
                              errorText: _isPhone ? null : "Phone number must not be empty",
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ]
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if(phoneInput.text == ""){_isPhone = false;}
                    else{_isPhone = true;}

                    if(_isPhone == true){
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/authentication-code');
                    }
                  });
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Continue',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: "GraphikMedium",
                  ),
                ),
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                    RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))
                  ),
                  minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size.fromHeight(60.0)),
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
                  shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}

I've tried like substract the MediaQuery.of(context).size.height with 90 and in my emulator it works fine, but in my friend emulator it's too high so he substract it with 30.

You just need to let the SingleChildScrollView take the remaining space of the screen, and let the Button displayed in the bottom of the screen.
Widget Structure:
 Column[
        Expanded ----> SingleChildScrollView 
  // take the remaining space of the screen after putting your button 
        
        Your Button
       ]

Here's your widget:
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Container(
            width: 200,
            child: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(10.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                      value: 1, // Value for first step
                      backgroundColor: Color(0xD9D9D9D9),
                      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.amber),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 7.0),
                  Expanded(
                    child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                      value: 0.5, // Value for second step
                      backgroundColor: Color(0xD9D9D9D9),
                      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.amber),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 7.0),
                  Expanded(
                    child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                      value: 0.0, // Value for third step
                      backgroundColor: Color(0xD9D9D9D9),
                      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.amber),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text('Set up 2-step verification',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 24.0,
                                    fontFamily: "GraphikMedium")),
                            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                            Text(
                              'Enter your phone number so we can text you an authentication code.',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                  color: Colors.grey[700]),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                            Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'Phone',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                      fontSize: 16.0,
                                      color: Colors.blue,
                                      fontFamily: "GraphikMedium"),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                                Focus(
                                  onFocusChange: (focus) {
                                    setState(() {});
                                  },
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide:
                                              BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide:
                                              BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)),
                                      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide:
                                              BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                                      focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide:
                                              BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                                      hintText: 'Your phone number',
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ]),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                'Continue',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: "GraphikMedium",
                ),
              ),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                      RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))),
                  minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size.fromHeight(60.0)),
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
                  shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }

result:

btw: There's no need to nest Columns (Don't put a column inside another specially if they have the same alignments).
The widget in that answer nest columns, try to remove unneeded ones, to simplify widget structure.
Hope it helps you.

Thank you for your answer, I've tried it, but I want the button continue is in the bottom of the screen, how do I do it? I mean if we don't specify the height and use space between how the button is in the bottom of the screen

it's ok, let me see @Name
